# Как узнать все пропсы в компоненте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Я вытягиваю компонент из библиотеки компонентов, которую создала сама.

Вот пример одного из компонентов.

```
import React, {FC} from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
export interface MyButtonProps{
    color:string;
    background: string;
    fontSize: string;
    variant:string;
    cursor:string;
    padding:string;
    border:string;
    hoverColor:string;
    hoverBackgroundColor:string;
}
const MyButton:FC<MyButtonProps> = ({children, color, background, fontSize, variant, cursor, padding, border, hoverColor, hoverBackgroundColor,  ...props}) => {
    const Button = styled.button`
        padding: 10px 25px;
        font-size: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius:12px;
        transition: all .2s;
        ${variant === "light" 
            ?
            `background-color: white;
            border: 1pX solid #EEEFEF;
            color: #EEEFEF;
            :hover{
                color:#ADAFAE;
                background-color:white;
                border: 1pX solid #ADAFAE;
            }`
            : variant === "dark" ?
            `background-color: black;
            border: 1pX solid black;
            color: white;
            :hover{
                color:black;
                background-color:white;
            }`: ``
        }
    `
    const MyButton=styled(Button)`
        background: ${background};
        color:${color};
        font-size:${fontSize};
        padding:${padding}
        cursor:${cursor};
        border:${border};
        :hover{
            color: ${hoverColor};
            background-color: ${hoverBackgroundColor};
        }
    `

    return (
        <MyButton {...props}>
            {children}
        </MyButton>
    )
}

export default MyButton
```

Я создаю генератор сайтов, то есть у меня страница разделена на две части, с одной стороны все компоненты, которые у меня есть в библиотеки, с другой сам сайт.

Перетягиваю компонент на сам сайт, в следствие чего создаю компонент динамически, и тут для возможности изменения стилей (фон у кнопки поменять и т.д) мне нужно узнать все пропсы, которые имеются у компонента.

Как это можно сделать?

Создаю компонент примерно так

```
{React.createElement(MyButton, {...})}
```

Пишу все на React с использование TypeScript. Когда я создавала библиотеку компонентов, то у каждого компонента был интерфейс, как раз с указанием всех пропсов и их типов.

Можно ли получить этот интерфейс компонента?

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: по идее ts должен подсветить все нужные пропсы

Comment: Внесла изменения в вопрос

Comment: Т.е. Вы не импортировали готовую библиотеку компонентов, а создали свою?
Можно увидеть пример кода, всё таки?

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyButton: FC<MyButtonProps> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  console.log(props); // Вывод всех пропсов в консоль

  // Остальной код компонента
  return (
    // JSX разметка компонента
  );
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]